# Delay between toggle elements possible?

Tags: javascript, toggle, display

I am using .fadeToggle so that when I click on one of three divs, the other two fade to two different divs, while the one clicked remains. The problem is that, during the transition, the divs overlap so there is a split second when all four changing divs are visible (short but aesthetically unpleasant). How can I create a moment where the display of all four is set to none, so that the toggle is smooth?

Here is all the JavaScript so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[class^="col"]').click(function() {
        var m = $(this).attr('id');
        $('[class^="col"]').not(this).fadeToggle('slow');
        $('#' + m + 'p').fadeToggle('slow');
        $('#' + m + 't').fadeToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Something's not clear: you first cite three `<div>`s, then four! In the other hand, can you expose a fiddle to exactly understand what happens?

Comment: Hey! I see the confusion: there are three "spots" I want to fill, one of three stays the same while the other two change to two different ones (four). That's probably no clearer, so here is a JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/cusohu/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.queue()](https://api.jquery.com/queue/)

```
    $('[class^="col"]').not(this).fadeToggle('slow').queue(function() {
      $('#' + m + 'p').fadeToggle('slow');
      $('#' + m + 't').fadeToggle('slow');
    });
```

You might want to reverse this in some cases (put the ones inside first.)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't toggle back after the first click. I realize I didn't state that explicitly, but that's why I've used toggle.

Comment: Then use `$(el).stop(1)` as well. Like this: `$(...).stop(1).fadeToggle('slow');`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, but after going through several possibilities I found that using if/else statements gave the exact result I wanted. Should it help anyone else, here you go:
http://jsbin.com/cusohu/edit?js,output